# Hide 4 divs; swap out separately on click

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

I have 4 hidden divs on my page each with a "button div" at the top of the page so when I click `div1` button, the hidden `div1` will show. Then when I click `div2` button the `div1` hides and `div2` appears.

I know you can do:

```js
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div id="Div1"  style="display:none;">INFO</div>
<input type="button" name="div1" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" />
```

But this will only make the div appear and will stay there when the `div2` button is pressed. How can I get them to change out as the different buttons are pressed?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the other divs by specifying .style.dispay = "none"

```
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('Div3').style.display = "none";
   //etc...
}
```

Comment: What about the other 2 `div`s?

Comment: @ScottHunter same thing...

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use Javascript only? Using `jQuery` you could change it to:

```
<div id="Div1" class="myDiv" style="display:none;">INFO</div>
<input type="button" class="divButton" name="div1" value="Show Div"/>
```

And then create a *simple* function, something like:

```
$('.divButton').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.myDiv').hide();
    var myDiv = $(event.currentTarget).closest('myDiv');
    myDiv.show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the ID of the `div` to show on button click, and hide all the others:

```js
function showDiv(id) {
  var d= document.querySelectorAll('div');
  [].forEach.call(d, function(div) {
    div.classList.add('hidden');
  });
  document.getElementById(id).classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="Div1" class="hidden">Div 1</div>
<div id="Div2" class="hidden">Div 2</div>
<div id="Div3" class="hidden">Div 3</div>
<div id="Div4" class="hidden">Div 4</div>

<input type="button" value="Show Div 1" onclick="showDiv('Div1')" />
<input type="button" value="Show Div 2" onclick="showDiv('Div2')" />
<input type="button" value="Show Div 3" onclick="showDiv('Div3')" />
<input type="button" value="Show Div 4" onclick="showDiv('Div4')" />
```